# How to add routes in a React/Gatsby app when I use i18next to handle translation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, gatsby, i18next

so recently I have been implementing an internationalization feature in my Gatsby app, but it should be similar to a React app, so if you know React, please tell me your experience too, thanks!

To enable the translation feature, I use `react-i18next`. My file structure looks like this:

```
-src
  -locale
   -en
     -translation.js
   -zh
     -translation.js
  -pages
   -index.js
   -......js
```

So what is going on is that, I extract all the text on files in `pages` folder and put them in `translation.js` in different language folders, and when I click a button to change the language, all the files in `pages` will find the corresponding text from different language `translation.js` file accordingly.

But the route doesn't change at all. Is there a way for me to be able to do this: **when I change the language, my route will change from `/en/index` to `/zh/index`?**

I know that I can make different pages, but I don't want to do that, I want to keep my current handling to separate my text from the app. Is there a package that I can use or what do you use to handle this? Thank you!

Comment: Why do translations change the route? The route should stay the same, the point of translations is that the text in the components changes.

Comment: @JMadelaine According to Gatsby website, it seems to make Google easily find the website and improve SEO performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the language itself will not change the route. You will need to use the gatsby router to do that (via: `await navigate('/:lang/path/slug')`). Butt like @jMadelaine said, you shouldn't need to change the route as it supports multi-language url routes in a single page component.

However, if you wish to do so can do the following below:

You can use the `i18next-browser-languagedetector` plugin and will need to include `path` or `querystring` in the `detection.order` array to be initialized in the i18next config for language detection.
https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector#detector-options

Then when initializing the i18next client you can use the language detector like this for example:

```
import i18next from "i18next"
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector"

const detection = {
  // order and from where user language should be detected
  order: [
    "querystring",
    "cookie",
    "localStorage",
    "navigator",
    "htmlTag",
    "path",
    "subdomain",
  ],

  // keys or params to lookup language from
  lookupQuerystring: "lng",
  lookupCookie: "i18next",
  lookupLocalStorage: "i18nextLng",
  lookupFromPathIndex: 0,
  lookupFromSubdomainIndex: 0,
  ...
}

i18next.use(LanguageDetector).init({
  detection, // <-- passed in here
  whitelist: ["en", "es"],
  fallbackLng: "en",
  resources: i18nResources,
  ns: ["translations"],
  defaultNS: "translations",
  returnObjects: true,
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  react: { wait: true },
  keySeparator: false,
  supportedLngs: ["en", "es"],
  lowerCaseLng: true,
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it now. But according to Gatsby website, it seems to make Google easily find the website and improve SEO performance